# Change or keep the value of a specific column considering the value in the same row and another column

Tags: r

I want to know how to change or keep the value of a specific column considering the value in the same row and another column.

Here is my dataset named (`df`):

```
          BLUP_pop          BLUPISM_rate
    1   1.94693747            1.00000000
    2   1.33774978            0.68710465
    3   1.04724481            0.78284058
    4   0.95897119            0.91570871
    5   0.75524367            0.78755616
    6   0.44728346            0.59223728
    7   0.35502008            0.79372504
    8   0.29392675            0.82791585
    9   0.26649710            0.90667862
    10  0.15827465            0.59390759
    11 -0.00630328           -0.03982495
    12 -0.21526737           34.15164327
```

I'd like to state the following rule:

- If `df$BLUP_pop <= 0`, then paste "0" in `df$BLUPISM_rate`;
- If `df$BLUP_pop >= 0`, then keep the value.

i.e.

```
          BLUP_pop          BLUPISM_rate
    1   1.94693747            1.00000000
    2   1.33774978            0.68710465
    3   1.04724481            0.78284058
    4   0.95897119            0.91570871
    5   0.75524367            0.78755616
    6   0.44728346            0.59223728
    7   0.35502008            0.79372504
    8   0.29392675            0.82791585
    9   0.26649710            0.90667862
    10  0.15827465            0.59390759
    11 -0.00630328            0
    12 -0.21526737            0
```

Thanks.

Comment: `df$BLUPISM_rate<-ifelse(df$BLUP_pop<=0,0,df$BLUPISM_rate)`

Comment: Or even simpler: `df$BLUPISM_rate <- df$BLUPISM_rate * (df$BLUP_pop > 0)`

Comment: or `df$BLUP_pop[df$BLUP_pop <= 0 ] <- 0`

Comment: For all your suggestions I got the following message:

   `Error in df$BLUPISM_rate : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Answer (score 0):

`BLUPISM_rate` is an existing column in data frame `df` which can be modified according to other column `BLUP_pop` based of condition using `ifelse`.

`mutate` is a function in [`dplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) package to do manipulations in existing or new columns in given data frame

```
# ifelse(condition,TRUE,FALSE)

library(dplyr)

    df <- df %>%
        mutate(
         BLUPISM_rate = ifelse(BLUP_pop <= 0 , 0 , BLUPISM_rate)
        )

    print(df)
```